US to CAN - wrong exit date stamp
Canadian citizen visiting the US. Upon entering this time, I had CBP ask for my departure date because of a security concern. I didn't receive an I94 or anything like that since it's leisure travel. I'm leaving on the 12th of August to go back to Canada, but instead received a stamp for the 11th. Am I gonna get flagged when trying to leave? How would I go about correcting this exit stamp?

By "exit date stamp", do you mean the "Until" date on the stamp you received when entering the US?

A photo of the passport stamp you're asking about would be useful in answering your question. Use the "Edit" button below your question, then select the "Moon and Mountains" tab, and drag a picture into the question text edit box; the photo will be added into your question.

"I didn't receive an I94 or anything like that since it's leisure travel." You did receive an I-94, but I-94s issued at entry have been electronic for the last decade. Go to https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/ to look up your I-94 that was issued at entry

I don't fully understand your question, but on the US side everything is electronic and the stamp (if given) is just a guide/souvenir for you.

@user102008 thanks, but when I checked that, my most recent arrival was not listed

@lambshaanxy they wrote in pen "August 11" followed by a note saying "LIMITED STAY"

@user156139: Then contact a CBP deferred inspection office for help in locating your I-94. Sometimes they misspelled your name or passport number.
